# Dropdown menu not working when hovering on button

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to build a dropdown menu but can't get dropdown to display when I hover on button.
I've checked the css on a website  that looks for faults, and it says there are none.
I've also followed W3schools dropdown css chapter almost to the letter and cant make it work.
I've been debugging this for 3 days. Please help. I;ve been coding for around 3 months.
Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    AGAIN3
  </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      font-family: arial;
      padding: 30px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: purple;
      color: yellow;
      z-index: 1;
      min-width: 160px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: white;
      background-color: pink;
      display: block;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
    
    .dropdown:hover.dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    /* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
    
    .container:hover .button {
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">hover</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">UEFA</a>
      <a href="#">FIFA</a>
      <a href="#">SFA</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `.dropdown:hover.dropdown-content` to `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content` (note the space). Flagged as *simple typographical error*.

Comment: @domdom Unless the OP doesn't know the difference between the two

Comment: @Ezenhis technically true, but even then the question, as-is, is of no future value and my comment should be sufficient for OP to research the difference by themselves as there is plenty of information available (on SO as well as elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight syntax issue with one your CSS rules.

```
.dropdown:hover.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

should be changed to

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Note the space between the `.dropdown:hover` and `.dropdown-content`.

The `.dropdown-content` is child element of `.dropdown` container and hence the selector should be `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`

Comment: can i ask .. why the downvotes ? The downvote should be used if the answer is "not useful" not if you personally think it should be there or not

Comment: someone is insta-downvoting all answers here

Comment: all the answers have downvotes !? who is this troll.. let me find out

Comment: Low-quality question (including questions that, because of their nature, are of no actual value for future readers), should be closed rather than answered. A lesson I had to learn the hard way as well, but it actually makes sense.

Comment: maybe it's the OP as well. I don't see him commenting

Comment: A question with syntax error is not a "low quality question". The OP doesnot know the difference between the CSS selectors & that's the reason why he cant solve his issue. Its not like he knew it and purposely posted it. Please understand the question & start insta-downvoting all. Its a common mistake yes, but not a low quality question.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I don't really know to be honest. Anyway, I commented the solution and flagged as typo, that far I'm sure it was fine.

Comment: The right way if you think it should be closed is by requesting the "close" option **on the question** & not spam downvote on all the answers in this thread.

Comment: Sorry if the question isn't good. I tried the syntax fix and it has worked perfectly. Thank you. Very frustrating; don't know how I missed this!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Instead of

```
.dropdown:hover.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is it on code pen. https://codepen.io/SoumyaMahbub/pen/gRoyXL